# Loop through table rows, calculate (multiply) input values, set result in another input

Tags: jquery, each

Given this html:

```
<table class="hours-table">
    <tr>
        <th>Hours</th>
        <th>Hourly Rate</th>
        <th>Date Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="hours"><input type="text" class="hours" name="hours-01" value="" /></td>
        <td class="rate"><input type="text" class="rate" name="rate-01" value="" /></td>
        <td class="date-total"><input type="text" class="date-total" name="date-total-01" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<p><a class="calculate" href="#" title="calculate row">Calculate</a></p>
```

I'm trying to loop through the rows, get the hours and rate values in each row, multiply them and set that value in the 'date-total' input (doesn't necessarily have to be an input for the total but I will be making another calculation on multiple columns as well)

Scratching my head for hours why a thousand attempts to get those values is not working, e.g.:

```
$('.calculate').on('click', function() {
    $('.hours-table tr').each(function() {
        var hours = $(this).find('input.hours').val(); // nope
        var hours = $('input.hours', this).val(); // nope
        var hours = $('input.hours', $this).val(); // nope
        //var dateTotal = (hours * rate);
        //$(this).find('input.date-total').val(dateTotal);
        return false;
    }) //END .each
}) // END click
```

Please, what the heck am I doing wrong with this loop?

Comment: Works for me - http://jsfiddle.net/Lr5pq/1/ . I'm not sure what you were meaning with the `return false;` but I think you wanted to prevent the default behavior of the `<a class="calculate">` - so I moved it out of the inner loop

Comment: Setting up a js fiddle , have an answer shortly

Comment: Returning false in the `.each()` callback will exit the loop. That's probably not what you want. @Ian, you should make your comment an answer.

Comment: @jrummell True, but it's weird that it didn't even work for the first (and only) row in the table. You would think it would process the first `<tr>` and then no more

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `return false;` in a `$.each` loop will exit it. I think you meant for the `return false;` to be for the `click` handler - to prevent the default behavior of the `<a>` and stop the event propagation. So if you move the `return false;` out one level, it seems to work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.calculate').on('click', function() {
        $('.hours-table tr').each(function() {
            var hours = $(this).find('input.hours').val();
            var rate = $(this).find('input.rate').val();
            var dateTotal = (hours * rate);
            $(this).find('input.date-total').val(dateTotal);
        }); //END .each
        return false;
    }); // END click 
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Lr5pq/1/

**UPDATE:**

The problem with getting `undefined` and `NaN` is because this is selecting all `<tr>` elements - that includes your header row:

```
<tr>
    <th>Hours</th>
    <th>Hourly Rate</th>
    <th>Date Total</th>
</tr>
```

Since your loop was exiting immediately after the first (where the first row was the header row), any `console.log`/debugging was for the header row. So of course, there would be no elements found. To fix that, you should be using `<thead>` and `<tbody>` to separate purpose. So your table should look like:

```
<table class="hours-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Hours</th>
            <th>Hourly Rate</th>
            <th>Date Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="hours"><input type="text" class="hours" name="hours-01" value="" /></td>
            <td class="rate"><input type="text" class="rate" name="rate-01" value="" /></td>
            <td class="date-total"><input type="text" class="date-total" name="date-total-01" value="" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And your `tr` selector should be:

```
$('.hours-table').find('tbody').find('tr').each(function() {
```

(I like using `.find()` instead of a long selector, but the point is that you add the `tbody` part to target just the `<tbody>` rows)

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Lr5pq/4/

Comment: Thanks Gents. Unbelievable oversight on my part. Pardon me while I step away and bash my head against the wall for a few more minutes. I'll be fine.

Comment: Thx Ian, indeed - I was sufficiently confused by undefined and NaN that I didn't realize the loop was exiting; I wasn't adding rows every time I tested.

Comment: @shecky Haha no problem. This is what the majority of problems on here are - just silly mistakes, so don't worry. Anyways, I just updated my answer to address why `undefined` and `NaN` were being returned...I can't believe I didn't see it before.

Comment: Thanks Ian, well done, I should have caught that sooner myself.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! I was just about to dive into it, actually I had another snippet for reference but I think yours is clearer, more concise. Also cool that using .keyup doesn't require loop. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use following.

```
 $("#hours-table tr").each(function () {
    var hours = $(this).find(".hours input").val();
    var rate = $(this).find(".rate input").val();
    var total= (hours * rate);
   $(this).find(".total input").val(total);  // Updates text box
```

});